# How to prevent activities to show up from background when transparent activity is opened from widget?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appwidget

I am using AndroidStudio and I have an activity with `Theme.Dialog`

```xml
<activity
      android:name=".widgets.MiniTrackerConfigureActivity"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
      android:noHistory="true"
      android:excludeFromRecents="true">
```

which is opened by clicking on **`App Widget`**, but when the my app is in the background and **`App Widget`** gets clicked, **`MiniTrackerConfigureActivity`** is opened **on top of activities in the background:**

[app in the background] -> [App Widget] -> [App Widget clicked]

[image: (1) image in background (2) app widget (3) app widget clicked]

**What I want is in spite of whether app is or not opened in the background:**
If `App Widget` is clicked, activity is opened on homescreen

[App Widget] -> [App Widget clicked]

[image: (1) App Widget (2) App Widget clicked]

**But if app is in the background, app shouldn't be destroyed or its activity stack affected!!**

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining a **style** extending **Theme.Dialog** like this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
</style>
```

in a **values** xml file (for example: **res/values/theme.xml**)
and them use that style on your **activity**:

```
<activity
    android:name=".widgets.MiniTrackerConfigureActivity"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true">
```

This should lead to a similar result to what you described - an empty background showing just the device wallpaper, regardless of what activities are currently open.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, and adding 
`android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to your widget activity should help.